# Nominal Type for String Literals

Tags: typescript

I like to use string literals as discriminated unions for many reasons, including to use the `never` type to check exhaustiveness in control flow.  For example:

```js
type PossibleStrings = "foo" | "moo" | "goo"

const stringHandler = (str:PossibleStrings) => {
    switch(str) {
        case "foo":
          return
        case "moo":
         return
        case "goo":
          return
        default:
          const x:never = str
    }
}

const badStringHandler = (str:PossibleStrings) => {
    switch(str) {
        case "foo":
          return
        case "moo":
         return
        default:
          const x:never = str // Error because a case is missing.  Yay.
    }
}
```

I also like to use nominal types for situations where I want structurally identical types to be incompatible.  I typically use the "branded interface" method (i.e., the third method [here](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/nominaltyping)).  For example:

```js
interface Nominal extends String {
     _brand: string
 }

 const toNominal = (str:string)=>str as unknown as Nominal

 const x:Nominal = "foo" // Error as expected
 const y:Nominal = toNominal("foo")
```

I've been trying to find some way to combine these two things, i.e., to have nominally typed strings that behave like string literals for purposes of exhaustiveness checking.

So, I created an extension of nominal type that uses the the string literal itself as an additional brand.  That way these "nominal literal" types will still be type compatible with the "wider" nominals.  But they can also be used like literals in the sense that they can be used as a narrow type that is incompatible but anything other than another nominal constructed with the same literal.  An example should make that clearer:

```js
 interface NominalLiteral<T extends string> extends Nominal {
     _literalBrand: T
 }

 const toNominalLiteral = <T extends string>(str:T)=>str as unknown as NominalLiteral<T>

 type PossibleNominals = NominalLiteral<"foo"> | NominalLiteral<"goo"> | NominalLiteral<"moo">

 let a:PossibleNominals = toNominal("foo") //Error as expected
 let b:PossibleNominals = toNominalLiteral("foo")
 let c:PossibleNominals = toNominalLiteral("gar") //Error as expected
 let d: Nominal = toNominalLiteral("foo") // Still type compatible with the wider nominal type
```

All well and good.  The problem is--Typescript doesn't seem to be able to detect when a set of these NominalLiteral types has been exhausted.  So this doesn't work:

```js
 type PossibleNominals = NominalLiteral<"foo"> | NominalLiteral<"goo"> | NominalLiteral<"moo">

 const nominalHandler = (nom:PossibleNominals) => {
    switch(nom) {
        case toNominalLiteral("foo"):
          return
        case toNominalLiteral("moo"):
         return
        case toNominalLiteral("goo"):
          return
        default:
          const x:never = nom //Error here.  TS doesn't realize that we've exhausted the PossibleNominals
    }
}
```

Any ideas on why this doesn't work?  Am I missing something easy or is this a TS limitation?  Is there any other way to make this work?

EDIT: Forgot the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=44&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGVgCdkB2A5glALxQBEAZnHJVAD5UC2dDzlR7AsAFD8AxnAIJgUMfmIAJAIYEAJplzkoACkkAueEjSYcUkgEpyAPigBvflBsSA7smCCAFhrwmrfW96iDZCaBp2TWsfb1wIYABXXAJQsL8A1mD4sIjo2NTvRMDuehCvMNt0mLjCsIUIalko9GACotthUXEAD00CCAA3CBUKSVSAX35hgT5msShUWQUDQiI5RWVVN1xtRBQMbDx5hBMyc09vBAcnV0kPLKb-QNp8q-DI0offG%20T78rSnzM-vSuravUXjYJm0Ot1eqpJFAAPQwqAAUVwuDgKlQED8USSsleSWQpBY%20JQxAAdDYAJqyEAkoYjfj8OFQLAQaDOYDAMAITRw6YIWS4WTAElERyoOgAaxJyDgMNAkAQgnwYGAMJYskIAFoAIwwghwQkEWR1cDzKD8QjAXrVQTQABy%20sIRqgEFalsUpDmxEsWQA%20qgBYpNBIdsRrKNrKCoMA4PaDU6KKtNJJ5kYDtD-FAogRxXq7AQoBnY470PSvJH2kXDehVEF6LD4UiUSoMy7IIJLQoIyJJiBNJX41GYw6q2pa5QjKWoBarbIbVB%20%20gADKOXpGgA8ABVna6IO7g4ZzC63QpSAvvb8fegVwL0AAhAMKIMbsOTyPRhfLy031Sb7fH0jJsQpiJhuqamOmpBZjmcB5gWp7Dkan6rugm6mJOcrQDomyYAupAUB%2017rmO5jMARX5EXklAkfOCFLoRKGUGw9BoWMUCYOIsjrLoWy4ao760aOdzjvWjaonB25th21jsVMXHYRAvEUPxcZ0eR6CCewE5eDJghyXoCm0Xhg5kcho5EPywlwqJzakK2GJSdpkRQI%20NEqXxQ4qUhN4afQJiMjgyDoNWGG%20PqYCCvpUCnM4UbONADiVCoepuRhr7duIyXFosSiQgmyV6Txhn7IcqQnI4LhqMlly-NcSTKcWXlGj544NI0UAlD8jQ5MZtGNepjGaa1RQdWUXVvPVVZ9WZg3Au13yjUU-w1HUQ1FOW4I9H0UDJSJyJiXFERklAG5YM5cAQAgBAAOTiBERrIAAXtAwDOIKUUQFdPTbq9WIdrFmEbPpuG0nwgxAA).

Comment: With primitives, one usually does `type NominalLiteral<T extends string> = T & {__brand: string}`.  Is there a reason you are using the `String` interface instead of the `string` type?  This doesn't solve your problem or anything, I'm just wondering why you're bringing wrapper objects into this.

Comment: That’s how the basarat book does it in the link I cited, which is where I learned it. But no good reason other than that. I guess an intersection would work as well as an interface extension and then I could avoid the wrappers

Comment: Yeah, I get "branded primitives" from [the TS FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal). This makes it so that your string literals are actually string literals and not `String`, so `const foo: "foo" = toNominalLiteral("foo");` will work ([see here](https://tsplay.dev/mb089w)).  I don't know if this constitutes an answer to your question, though, since you didn't ask about that, and again, it doesn't solve the exhaustiveness issue. I haven't found any GitHub issue mentioning brands & narrowing together, so I don't know why it doesn't work for that.

Answer (score 0):

This would work, although a bit ugly:

```js
interface NominalLiteral<T extends string> extends Nominal {
  _literalBrand: T
}

const toNominalLiteral = <T extends string>(str:T)=> {
  const r = `${str}` as unknown as NominalLiteral<T>;
  r._literalBrand = str;
  return r;
}

type PossibleNominals = NominalLiteral<"foo"> | NominalLiteral<"goo"> | NominalLiteral<"moo">

const nominalHandler = (nom: PossibleNominals) => {
  switch(nom._literalBrand) {
    case "foo":
      return
    case "moo":
      return
    case "goo":
      return
    default:
      const x: never = nom
  }
}
```

It makes ts handle it as algebraic data types.

Comment: I get a Javascript error when I try this that `Cannot create property '_literalBrand' on string 'foo'`, which makes sense (I think) since these  nominal types are _really_ just strings, I'm just pretending to TS they have these other properties.

It will work if I use the boxed type, i.e., change your first line to `const r = new String(`${str}`) as unknown as NominalLiteral<T>`

Comment: So basically this is creating discriminated unions that look like `{String:"foo",_literalBrand:"foo"} | {String:"goo",_literalBrand:"goo"}` and then switching on the discriminant?  Too bad you actually have to create that javascript...

Comment: Yes indeed. That's a very inconvenient path. I very much hope there's a better solution someone'd bring here.